# Dynamic dispatch on traits with associated types and generic implementations

Tags: generics, rust, traits, associated-types

I want to have a `Rectangle` type that is generic over its dimensions which implements an `Area` trait. The only requirement on the output of this trait is for it to be `Display`able. The requirement for generic dimensions is contrived, but I'm treating it as a learning example. The following compiles just fine:

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::ops;

trait Area{
    type Output: fmt::Display;
    fn area(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

struct Rectangle <T, U>{
    width: T,
    height: U,
}

impl <T, U> Area for Rectangle<T, U>
where T: ops::Mul<U> + Copy, U: Copy,
<T as ops::Mul<U>>::Output: fmt::Display
{
    type Output = <T as ops::Mul<U>>::Output;
    fn area(&self) -> Self::Output {
        self.width * self.height
    }
}


fn main(){
    let float_r = Rectangle {width: 1.5_f64, height: 2.5_f64};
    let int_r = Rectangle {width: 2_i32, height: 3_i32};
    println!("Area of rectangle is {}", float_r.area());
    println!("Area of rectangle is {}", int_r.area());
}
```

I now want to refactor the logging lines into a function that accepts any type which implements `Area` to later user with e.g a `Circle` type:

```rust
fn log_shape(s: &dyn Area){
    println!("Area of rectangle is {}", s.area());
}
```

but this does not compile unless I define the `Output` in the function signature:

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `Output` (from trait `Area`) must be specified
  --> src/main.rs:24:22
   |
5  |     type Output: fmt::Display;
   |     -------------------------- `Output` defined here
...
24 | fn log_shape(s: &dyn Area){
   |                      ^^^^ help: specify the associated type: `Area<Output = Type>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0191`.
```

however, I don't want to do this, since if I define a circle:

```rust
struct Circle<T>{
    radius: T
}
```

the `Output` for `Circle`'s implementation of `Area` is of type `<<T as ops::Mul<T>>::Output as ops::Mul<f64>>::Output` (corresponding to `self.radius * self.radius * pi`): which is a different type to that of `Rectangle`'s area.

Is my intended use of associated types in this context misguided? If so, what is the advised way of achieving my desired functionality?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot do `fn log_shape(s: &impl Area)`? Why is dynamic dispatch required here?

Comment: Ah yes, fair point. If you allow me to shift the goal posts a little: suppose I wanted a function that would take a list of  `Area` objects: `fn log_shapes(shapes: &[dyn Area])` which may be a mix of `Rectangle`s and `Circle`s

Comment: That can only work if the trait function returns `Box<dyn fmt::Display>` because with a heterogeneous slice of `Area`s you'd have no way to know the _size_ of each of the output values, let alone where the `Display` impl is.

Comment: I see! Okay with this I can achieve what I want while maintaining the abstractions in the post. Thanks for your time, if you wish you can post this as an answer which I'd then happily accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that when you call `s.area()`, the return type needs to have a sized, known type, which is why the error wants you to specify it.

A few ways around this (mostly from the comments):

## 1. Print inside a trait method

Here I made a new trait but you may want to replace your existing trait [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c73bc2a33da4fe8f9c2e98ccbfcfc6aa).

```rs
impl<T, U> Area for Rectangle<T, U>
where
    T: ops::Mul<U> + Copy,
    U: Copy,
{
    type Output = <T as ops::Mul<U>>::Output;
    fn area(&self) -> Self::Output {
        self.width * self.height
    }
}

trait Log {
    fn log(&self);
}

impl<T> Log for T
where
    T: Area,
    T::Output: Display,
{
    fn log(&self) {
        println!("Area of rectangle is {}", self.area());
    }
}

fn log_shape(s: &dyn Log) {
    s.log()
}
```

## 2. Use static dispatch

This is more idiomatic and likely faster if your use case allows [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=98043bd78644d7212394f17f8c0d81c1).

```rs
fn log_shape<A: Area>(s: A) {
    println!("Area of rectangle is {}", s.area());
}
```

## 3. Return a trait object from the trait method

This is likely slower and has a different flavor, yet similar level, of flexibility to the first method [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0c5f0941d46261cf2d9b0bcbaa3956ab).

```rs
trait Area {
    fn area(&self) -> Box<dyn Display>;
}

impl<T, U> Area for Rectangle<T, U>
where
    T: ops::Mul<U> + Copy,
    U: Copy,
    <T as ops::Mul<U>>::Output: Display + 'static,
{
    fn area(&self) -> Box<dyn Display> {
        let a = self.width * self.height;
        Box::new(a)
    }
}
```

In summary: #1 works with trait objects while being performant (no extra allocations). If you have it take a `Formatter` parameter like in `Display::fmt`, you can use it to write to any writer. #2 is the most idiomatic and fastest if you can use it. #3 lets you leave the `log_shape` function unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! In fact solution 3 is what I arrived at after u/cdhowie comment

Answer (score 3):

In general, the recommendation will be to use static dispatch. However, if you must use dynamic dispatch, and you cannot change the trait, a nice idea is to use *type erasure*.

The idea is to define a new trait, `ErasedArea`, that has a blanket implementation for every `Area` out there but it also type safe by erasing the `Output` type and returning `Box<dyn fmt::Display>`:

```rust
trait ErasedArea {
    fn area(&self) -> Box<dyn fmt::Display + '_>;
}

impl<T: ?Sized + Area> ErasedArea for T {
    fn area(&self) -> Box<dyn fmt::Display + '_> {
        Box::new(<Self as Area>::area(self))
    }
}

fn log_shape(s: &dyn ErasedArea) {
    println!("Area of rectangle is {}", s.area());
}
```